# How to solve a minimization problem with infinite norm objective?

Tags: matrices, optimization

Recently, I came up with an idea on my research about beamforming. It can be formulated as,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{w \in \mathbb{C}^{1\times N}}{\text{minimize}} & \| H w^H \|_{\infty} \\ \text{subject to} & a w^H = 1\end{array}$$

where matrix $H \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$ and vector $a \in \mathbb{C}^{1\times N}$ are given.

I haven't found any paper or method to solve it. My question is how to solve this kind of infinite norm objective function. Is there any fixed way to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem was set over real numbers the you could do the following.
You can introduce an auxiliary variable $t\ge0$, that encodes the $\infty$-norm:
$$
-t \le (Hw^H)_i \le t.
$$
Then minimize $t$ subject to these linear constraints. The resulting problem is now a linear programming problem.

For this complex case, one can do similar:
$$
|(Hw^H)_i| \le t.
$$
You end up with more constraints ...

Comment: really thanks! I will try this method!

Comment: Sorry for bother you again.For complex case, Can  I use cvx to solve this problem?